# loop through observable array of knockout property

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am using knockout mapping library to bind JSON data from .NET service to a property in KO view model, in which the property has an array of objects that I need to loop through and render on the screen.

The .NET model:

```
new{
    count = count,
    total = total,
    rows = items,
}
```

the rows property holds list of objects, which needs to be rendered into a table using KO.

I tired using

```
<!-- ko foreach: masterData().rows-->
<tr>
    <td><span data-bind='text:  Id' /></td>
    <td><span data-bind='text:  Name' /></td>
    <td><span data-bind='text:  Description' /></td>
    <td><span data-bind='text:  Status' /></td>
</tr>
<!-- /ko -->
```

where the masterData is an observable. After data load, it renders nothing inside the table. As a workaround, I have changed the model the observable to observableArray([])

```
new List<dynamic> { 
    new
    {
        count = recCount,
        total = total,
        rows = items,
    }};
```

and changed the rendering logic to

```
<!-- ko foreach: masterData -->
<!-- ko foreach: rows-->
<tr>
    <td><span data-bind='text:  Id' /></td>
    <td><span data-bind='text:  Name' /></td>
    <td><span data-bind='text:  Description' /></td>
    <td><span data-bind='text:  Status' /></td>
</tr>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

Now it works as expected. There should be a better way of dealing with this or I am missing something I suppose. Also, I needed to loop through this list in order to access other properties.

EDIT 1:

http://jsfiddle.net/krishnasarma/hdt9ehth/

Comment: I think you just need to make your first one `foreach: masterData().rows()`.

Comment: That is strange... if think it should work fine. Provide a JSFiddle with your code and an example data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well i tweaked your code little bit to make it ideal . I see not point looping `masterData` for getting `rows` data .

we can now use `with` binding which is perfect for such scenario stated above.

**view:**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="with:masterData2">
        <!-- ko foreach:rows -->
        <tr>
            <td><span data-bind='text:  Id' /></td>
            <td><span data-bind='text:  Name' /></td>
            <td><span data-bind='text:  Description' /></td>
            <td><span data-bind='text:  Status' /></td>
        </tr>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**viewModel:**

```
var VM = {
    masterData: ko.observable([]), //initializing 
    masterData2: ko.observable([])
}
```

sample working fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/hdt9ehth/2/)**

If you want to in a *Lazy Loading* way check **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/hdt9ehth/6/)**